# How could I query binary's source code version

Tags: c++, c, linux, version-control

My environment is Linux CentOS 6.2. And I've a source control system like svn/hg/git etc. My source code is C/C++.

I want to check in the build binary to keep which binary is release to customer.

And I assume build binary's checksum will different when source code changed.
So, I could reverse trace which binary is build from which version.

Is it possible, what's the tricks I must follow?

I've seen some executable display the revision when execute with -version option.
But I'm wonder how to prevent write wrong -version string into the executable.

If I keep a md5.txt and check-in it instead of check in binary.
How could I make sure I can build the same md5 executable again?

Sorry, for clearing my question and preventing another unexpected answer, I prefer a answer like:

1. Keep a md5sum.txt in scm when release a new version to user.
2. Keep binary separate from your SCM.
3. To rebuild the same md5sum binary you should make sure

   - write symbol into binary when make(eg. by -DVERSION="1.x")
   - show the VERSION string to user
   - remove all $Id, that let your SCM run slower.
   - keep same CPU & OS & compiler & library environment
   - ...

Comment: Don't check in binaries. No, just don't.

Comment: You don't need to checkin the binary.  If you MUST record something, just check in the MD5 or SHA1 checksums (in ASCII format).

Comment: And if you *do* check in binaries, why would you check in a binary that's built from anything other than the source tree that the binary is checked in alongside?  If you ask the source control system which revision last modified the binary file, and check out that revision, you should be able to trust that it contains the code that the binary was built from.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Sometimes it is a very very good idea to check binaries to ensure that what you are using is what you think you are using. This is true if you have received binaries that your collegue has built. We all make mistakes once in a while - it is called being human.

Comment: @EdHeal - it doesn't mean you have to commit binaries in VCS. You have only know, which revision of **sources** was used for building binary

Comment: @LazyBadger - I did not say that you should commit binaries in a VCS. But it is useful to be able to tell what source was used to build the binary. A few occasions a person has made a mistake in the build process and then you start testing - thinking that it should fix a particular bug. Instead of spending days doing the testing we used the method that I described below to ensure that we would not waste time on somebody making a mistake that can be fixed before commencement of testing.

Comment: @Ed Heal: you should put the binary outside of the version control system. You could put inside only its checksum!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - checksum?! When I have 1. sources 2. Already in VCS?! Don't re-invent the wheel

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - That is what I said. But you can include into the binary version contol information from the source code. You are then able to confirm that the binary delivered to you was constructed from the various versions of source code. Please read my comments above and also the answer below.

Comment: I'm wonder, if I release a binary to customer. The md5sum of the executable will be same when I rebuild on the same version?  As I know, it may different. How to make sure it will generate the same binary?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create strings within a .cpp file as thus:

   `static const char version[] = "@(#) $Id$";`

   where $Id$ is obtained from SVN
2. Use the *what* command (see the manual page). It will obtain these strings from the binary so you can check.

Comment: Does the `@(#)` serve anything else besides being a searchable pattern for a hexdumper?

Comment: I've used **what** command on SunOS, but that is not default linux command.  And that tech may let binary different even when my source code just move from repository_A to repository_B.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an executable or a shared library? If the latter, you could export a function that would return the version (number, string, your choice). Then dlopen(), dlsym(), and execute the function.

For executable ELF binaries, you might be able to implant some data in the binary that can be queried using the 'nm' utility.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll use Subversion, [SvnRev](http://www.compuphase.com/svnrev.htm) will do most work for you (no md5 in repos, repo hold sources, binary - resource with revision-id)

For Mercurial, you can get idea for version sting from [VersioningWithMake](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/VersioningWithMake) wiki, and in order to get string like result of git describe, instead of simple template {node|short} for HGVERSION you can use something as `{latesttag}+{latesttagdistance}:{node|short}`, showing (example) `1.3+11:8a226f0f99aa`